# How/where to find precedent civil cases (Canada)?

Tags: canada, legal-research, precedent, civil-judgment

I am interested in learning about some civil cases that happened in the past. What are the resources that one could use to find thematic breakdown of such cases? For example, where would I be able to see civil cases on tenant vs landlord? Interested jurisdiction - Canada.

Comment: What jurisdiction(s) are you interested in? Adding the relevant state/country tag(s) to your question will help others.

Comment: US and Canada are so different jurisdictions, you should ask those two separately.

Comment: thanks! edited my question now.

Comment: Hard copies of annotated statutes and sometimes hard copies of a subject matter arrangement of summaries of legal holdings from court cases called a "digest" can be found in law libraries and bigger public libraries. There are also books on particular subject matter areas of law with citations to cases called "treatises".

Answer (score 2):

The [Canadian Supreme Court](https://decisions.scc-csc.ca/scc-csc/en/d/s/index.do?cont=Landlord+&ref=&d1=&d2=&p=&or=) and [CanLii](https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/type=decision&text=Landlord%20&resultIndex=10) have free online searchable databases of statutes and selected case law.

(Other providers are available but often they are behind a paywall, or require users to register an account or be affiliated with a particular organisation.)